# Sitecore Poll Module doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a Sitecore CMS 6.5 and I want to use Poll Module from here:
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Poll_Module.aspx
There is no CMS version in Download section so I have downloaded DMS Poll Module Version 2.0.0. I have installed it and it doesn't work.
For example when I click poll node in sitecore there is nullexception in this

```
Line 107:                        <%= FieldRenderer.Render(CurrentPollOptionItems[i].InnerItem, "Title")%>
Line 108:                        <span class="scDMSPollOptionItemResultValue">
Line 109:                            <%= CurrentPollOptionItems[i].GetVoteCountPercent().ToString("0")%>%</span>
Line 110:                    </span>
Line 111:                    <div class="scDMSPollVisualisation">
```

When I set placeholder for a poll and try to load page, there is message that there is no layout. I have published all items. Does this version (DMS) work with CMS? Or is there any simple example how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The OMS Poll Module does not work with Sitecore CMS 6.5. For 6.5 onwards you need to use DMS Poll Module.

If you are upgrading to the 6.5 version you can find the instructions here
http://elenazlateva.blogspot.com/2013/10/sitecore-upgrade-hassles-from-oms-poll.html